# how to hightlight visited links with tree structure?

Tags: php, css

I have list in tree structure. 
Example:
continent1 name
  country1 name
    city1 name

continent2 name
  country2 name
    city2 name

When i visit continent 1 it has to be highlighted, if country is visited country has to be highlighted similarly city

Again if i visit continent 2, this time continent 2 has to be highlighted not content 1

I am using php. Hope to get answer. 
Thanks...............

Comment: Do you need to highlight everything above the currently selected item too? Eg. if city1 is cliked, then country1 and continent1 have to be highlighted as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to style the [a:visited](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-visited) pseudo-class.